# Speedup parallel data download using ipython

Tags: ipython

I have a lot (~ 1000) of small files to download. I have written a function for this to be able to use map. The download-function itself uses requests which significantly improved stability over urllib2 which gave me lots of timeouts.
However, there is minor speedup when running in parallel on e.g. 4 processes compared to running the serial map:

```
data = map(get_data, IDs)
data = dview.map_sync(get_data, IDs)
```

I am not sure about:

- Is map_sync the best? I considered using map_async but I need the complete list to go one so this should not make a difference?
- What else can be done to speed-up the process?
- My expectation is to perform n downloads at the same time in parallel instead of one after another

Answer (score 1):

Since your downloads are IO limited, I would actually recommend a simple ThreadPool over IPython.parallel (*note: I am the author of IPython.parallel*). It's a lot easier to get going, and none of what IPython.parallel does really benefits your presented case.

I setup a [simple server](https://gist.github.com/minrk/6407393#file-slow_server-py) that slowly responds to requests to test.

Test a simple request to my slow server
It just replies to any request for `/NUMBER` with the number requested,
but the server is artificially slow in its handling of requests:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://localhost:8888/10")
r.content

'10'
```

Our `get_data` function downloads the URL for a given ID,
and parses the result (casts str of int to int):

```
def get_data(ID):
    """function for getting data from our slow server"""
    r = requests.get("http://localhost:8888/%i" % ID)
    return int(r.content)
```

Now test using a threadpool to get a bunch of data, using a varying number of concurrent threads:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

IDs = range(128)
for nthreads in [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]:
    pool = ThreadPool(nthreads)
    tic = time.time()
    results = pool.map(get_data, IDs)
    toc = time.time()
    print "%3i threads: %5.1f seconds" % (nthreads, toc-tic)


  1 threads:  26.2 seconds
  2 threads:  13.3 seconds
  4 threads:   6.7 seconds
  8 threads:   3.4 seconds
 16 threads:   1.8 seconds
 32 threads:   1.1 seconds
```

You can use this to figure out how many threads make sense for your case.  You can also easily replace ThreadPool with ProcessPool, and see if you get better results.

This example [as an IPython Notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/6407393/threadpool.ipynb).